# How do I force a 64-bit windows 8.1 install?

Tags: windows, installation, 64-bit

I have just purchased a copy of Windows 8.1 32-bit/64-bit from the MSDNAA program through my University. It came as an `.iso` file so I burned it to a DVD and installed / registered without any issues. I just found out it's a 32-bit install though, and I'm running a 64-bit laptop (Dell Studio 1555). The exact produce name I purchased is *Microsoft Windows 8.1 Professional 32/64-bit (English)*.

Is that just another name for "32-bit version that also works on 64-bit machines"?

I have 4GB and I would like to code for 64-bit architectures so not having a 64-bit environment will be a real pain. I didn't see any options to choose the install type (it had Windows 7 64-bit previously but I completely wiped it). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product is usually come in separately available ISOs each for x86 and x64 versions. Most probably you should check download page and see if you can get x64 version of the installation ISO.

Comment: I ended up finding a Windows 8 64-bit ISO which I'm using now (just have to upgrade to 8.1 manually). It's a shame Microsoft didn't make this process more transparent (why would you call a 32-bit-only version *32/64-bit*??).